# Insert image blob into mysql database from a mysql data row using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert, blob

I am using following Insert statement to insert Blob row read from one database into another. (there is data when i echo the same insert statement).

UPDATE:

```
"INSERT INTO co_registration_picture_evidence_blb
        (_URI, _CREATOR_URI_USER, _CREATION_DATE, _LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER, _LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
        _TOP_LEVEL_AURI, VALUE) VALUES('".$imageRow['_URI']."','".$imageRow['_CREATOR_URI_USER']."','"
        .$imageRow['_CREATION_DATE']."','".$imageRow['_LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER']."','".
        $imageRow['_LAST_UPDATE_DATE']."','".$imageRow['_TOP_LEVEL_AURI']."'".
        $imageRow['VALUE']."')"
```

I get following error message.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Update: Now i get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0?\0\0\0?\0\0\0????\0\0%iCCPICC Profile\0\0x??M' at line 3
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with the syntax? my guess is that i should wrap VALUE column that is of type LongBlob (that holds an image) to some encoding function. (all data fields are already mysql_real_escape_string() filtered).

Any input would be really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I think you are missing ")" at the end of your query. i.e `$imageRow['_TOP_LEVEL_AURI']."')"`

Comment: Yes that was missing. Now i get another error please see updated question.

Comment: can you add your query with value in question?

Comment: You are embarking on a dangerous path. You might want to read up on prepared statements and how to use them.

Comment: @techouse what do you mean by prepared statements?

Comment: Writing SQL statements like that is quite dangerous, especially if the data comes from something dynamic, like an input form. Consider using placeholders and bind values to them instead. This way the database class will automatically escape & sanitize everything before any queries are run. Read more here: http://si1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `, '`

```
INSERT INTO co_registration_picture_evidence_blb
        (_URI, _CREATOR_URI_USER, _CREATION_DATE, _LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER, _LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
        _TOP_LEVEL_AURI, VALUE) VALUES('".$imageRow['_URI']."','".$imageRow['_CREATOR_URI_USER']."','"
        .$imageRow['_CREATION_DATE']."','".$imageRow['_LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER']."','".
        $imageRow['_LAST_UPDATE_DATE']."','".$imageRow['_TOP_LEVEL_AURI']."', '".
        $imageRow['VALUE']."')
```

**What did I change?**

`'".$imageRow['_TOP_LEVEL_AURI']."'".`

`'".$imageRow['_TOP_LEVEL_AURI']."', '".`

Comment: I figured that out just now ... thanks! it works great now :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear.